# Proguard with native code in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, proguard

I have a jar which I want to shrink and obfuscate. It references a custom JNI library.
I have this in my proguard conf file:

```
# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

But still at runtime I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: error
    at com.test.model.Video.naInit(Native Method)
    at com.test.model.Video.a(Video.java:95)
    at com.test.ui.ExportWindow$8.run(ExportWindow.java:561)
```

Which is the first JNI method called in Video.java

```
private native int naInit(String inFileName, String outFileName);
```

I thought the above proguard line should keep all native names? Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?